# How to draw a image with effects that rescales with it's window in direct2d

Tags: c++, direct2d

I created a Direct2D application following this example: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/Direct2D/SimpleDirect2DApplication

I managed to show a bitmap in the applications window and the bitmap also rescales when rescaling the window. But now I wanted to apply effects on the bitmap and here comes my problem. The effect is applied like this

```
hr = m_pRenderTarget->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID2D1DeviceContext), (void**)&m_pDeviceContext );
m_pDeviceContext->CreateEffect( CLSID_D2D1GammaTransfer, &gammaTransferEffect );
gammaTransferEffect->SetInput( 0, m_pBitmap );
gammaTransferEffect->SetValue( D2D1_GAMMATRANSFER_PROP_RED_AMPLITUDE, 4.0f );
```

The problem is that after applying the effect, the image data is now in the format of [ID2D1Effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nn-d2d1_1-id2d1effect). This can be drawn with [DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1devicecontext-drawimage%28id2d1effect_constd2d1_point_2f_constd2d1_rect_f_d2d1_interpolation_mode_d2d1_composite_mode%29) like this:

```
m_pDeviceContext->DrawImage(gammaTransferEffect);
```

But I did the rescaling with `destinationRectangle` in the function [DrawBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/d2d1_1/nf-d2d1_1-id2d1devicecontext-drawbitmap(id2d1bitmap_constd2d1_rect_f__float_d2d1_interpolation_mode_constd2d1_rect_f__constd2d1_matrix_4x4_f_)) and there is no equivalent to `destinationRectangle` in `DrawImage`.

```
m_pDeviceContext->DrawBitmap(
            m_pBitmap,
            D2D1::RectF(
                0,
                0,
                renderTargetSize.width,
                renderTargetSize.height),
            1.0f,
            D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR
        );
```

So how can I rescale the bitmap after applying the effect when rescaling the render target? I had some ideas about this, but none led me to a solution.

1. Rescale the device context. I didn't find a method like [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1hwndrendertarget-resize(constd2d1_size_u)) for the rendert target.
2. Make a [bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1bitmap) from the effects output to use DrawBitmap again. I found no possibility to do this.
3. Rescaling the bitmap before applying effects on it. I found no way to do this.

Somebody an idea what could be a solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to my problem is to rescale the render target:

```
// Retrieve the size of the render target.
D2D1_SIZE_F renderTargetSize = m_pRenderTarget->GetSize();
// calculate scale factors
float scale_x = renderTargetSize.width / _bitmapSource.width;
float scale_y = renderTargetSize.height / _bitmapSource.height;
// scale render target
m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(
    D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Scale(
        D2D1::Size( scale_x, scale_y ),
        D2D1::Point2F( 0.0f, 0.0f ))
);
hr = m_pRenderTarget->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ID2D1DeviceContext), (void**)&m_pDeviceContext );
m_pDeviceContext->CreateEffect( CLSID_D2D1GammaTransfer, &gammaTransferEffect );
gammaTransferEffect->SetInput( 0, m_pBitmap );
gammaTransferEffect->SetValue( D2D1_GAMMATRANSFER_PROP_RED_AMPLITUDE, 4.0f );
m_pDeviceContext->DrawImage(gammaTransferEffect);
```

Additionally I had to remove my `resize` function from the `WM_SIZE` message, otherwise my painted bitmap didn't rescale with its window. That was a bit counter intuitive to me, but yay it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you gldhnchn.  I had the same problem.  In fact I encounter it even without the effect -- RenderTarget->DrawBitmap scales the image as desired, but DeviceContext->DrawImage does not, as demonstrated below.  Your fix does the trick.

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyImageCtrl, CStatic)

CMyImageCtrl::CMyImageCtrl()
{
    EnableD2DSupport();

    CImage image; 
    image.Load("test_bmap.jpg");
    m_pBitmap = new CD2DBitmap(GetRenderTarget(), image.Detach());
}

afx_msg LRESULT CMyImageCtrl::OnDraw2D(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CHwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget = (CHwndRenderTarget*)lParam;

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    CD2DRectF rectD(rect);

    bool bUseRenderTarget = true;
    if (bUseRenderTarget) {

        // here image scales to fit client
        pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(m_pBitmap, rectD);

    } else {

        // here image is drawn full native size, does not scale to rect
        CComQIPtr<ID2D1DeviceContext> spDeviceContext = pRenderTarget->GetRenderTarget();

        spDeviceContext->DrawImage(m_pBitmap->Get(), D2D1::Point2F(0., 0.), rectD);
    }
}
```